# Cleaning the text in R: Removing the web url link reference

Tags: r

I am in the process of cleaning the tweets for a text mining project in R. I have tweets with url link like this:

```
> inspect(data_corpus[1])

[1] Twirling around in the prettiest winery garden. @Newton Vineyard https://www. instagram.com/p/BVLZnSGDRG1/
```

**Question No.1:**

I want to remove whole link starting from https (https://www. instagram.com/p/BVLZnSGDRG1/)

I tried to apply this code, however it is just removing up to .com and not the complete link

```
toSpace = content_transformer( function(x, pattern) gsub(pattern," ",x) )
data_clean = tm_map(data_corpus, toSpace, "(f|ht)tp(s?)://(.*)[.][a-z]+")


> inspect(data_clean[1])

[1] Twirling around in the prettiest winery garden.  @Newton Vineyard  /p/BVLZnSGDRG1/
```

I want to remove the reference "/p/BVLZnSGDRG1/" as well. How to do this?

**Question No.2**:

I want to remove the screen names starting with @. However in the above tweet, the screen name is (@Newton Vineyard). When i applied the below code, it is just removing @Newton alone and not the Vineyard.

```
data_clean = tm_map(data_clean, toSpace, "@[a-z,A-Z]*")
```

Result:

```
> inspect(data_clean[1])

[1] Twirling around in the prettiest winery garden.     Vineyard  /p/BVLZnSGDRG1/
```

Is it possible to remove "Vineyard" as well?

My worry is that what if the word "Vineyard" is not part of the screen name and it is actually a string part of the tweet? Is it possible to check if "Vineyard" is part of the screen name and remove only if it so?

Comment: Is this `/p/BVLZnSGDRG1/` part of the URL?

Comment: Does the structure always follow the pattern tweet-username-link? If so, you can just use `sub("\\s?@.*", "", x)`

Comment: @docendodiscimus does the `?` after the sapce in your regex means that there might be a space might not be a space?

Comment: @Sotos, yes, that's correct

Comment: @Sotos yes, its part of URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove both url and username, you can use

```
@(?!.*@).*$
```

to remove the last @ sign andeverything beyond it. Explanation:

```
@       # literal character '@'
(?!     # negative lookahead (aka 'not followed by')
  .*    # any number of any character (except newlines)
  @     # literal character '@'
)       # end negative lookahead
.*      # any number of character
$       # end of line
```

This regular expression matches an @ not followed by an @, and everything from it until end of line.